# Is there a way to open a widget from inside another widget in zoho?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zoho

I have this use case of opening a widget from inside another widget in zoho.
For Example, I have a widget with a button that says, "Open XYZ widget", and when clicked it would programmatically open another widget. Can you please guide me If I can do that in Zoho?
Thanks

I did not try, I was just wondering if this is doable. This might be an upcoming scenario.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be do-able.

The 2nd widget may need to be embedded in a Zoho Page and the calling widget's button would then call the url of the Zoho Page.